# Use a method in combination with setText (android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

currently I'm working on a project for school, a kind of number game. In this project I have to add up the numbers of several buttons and put the result in a textview. For some reason I can't use the .setText order, because android studio "cannot resolve symbol setText".
Here is the Code:

```
 Button14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
            }
            TextView EditText1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
            EditText1.setText(Spalte1)


        }
        );



 public int Spalte1() {
    int Spalte1 = R.id.button14 + R.id.button20 + R.id.button12 + R.id.button21 + R.id.button13;
  return Spalte1;
}
```

I hope this is enough that you know what to do.

Comment: Put those two lines inside `onClick`.

Comment: make sure you know what you're doing. if you are not sure what you're doing, try to learn the fundamentals first with some tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Please fix your code, see what I suggest and let me know if this solve your issue.

Your code:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        }
        TextView EditText1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        EditText1.setText(Spalte1)
```

Move the EditText lines inside the onClick brackets.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        TextView EditText1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        EditText1.setText(Spalte1);
    }
```

Comment: There isn't a error message now, so hopefully the program does what I want. Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: welcome @Dennis By the way I suggest you to save the initialize 
`TextView EditText1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);` 

inside the onCreate() method.

Answer (score 1):

The code isn't working because your code is not in the correct place. A suggestion for you to avoid this errors is to always ident your code and check for errors IDE gives on the brackets.

```
Button14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView EditText1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        EditText1.setText(Spalte1()) // note I wrote Spalte1() instead of Spalte1
    }
});

public int Spalte1() {
    int Spalte1 = R.id.button14 + R.id.button20 + R.id.button12 + 
    R.id.button21 + R.id.button13;
    return Spalte1;
}

// functions must be written like function(arguments) if there are no arguments you write function(), that way it should be Splate1() above
```

## The logic works like this:

The code must be inside the **onClick** method because that's the code that will be run when you click the Button14. The code wrapping it (outside) is the way you create a new Listener (which listens for the Button14 click) and then calls the method onClick (which executes the code you provide).

Answer (score 0):

make it

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        TextView EditText1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        EditText1.setText(Spalte1)
        }
```